# How to create a :hover pseudo class selector for the *li's* inside a *ol* [CSS]?

Tags: css

The closest I got was `li:hover` but this targets the `ol`, rather than the `li` instead.

Does it look more along the lines of `ol:li:hover`? I tried doing that & anything like it, but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hi Waefu, welcome to SO! Show some [reprex] so people can see what's the issue...

Comment: If the user is hovering on an li element then the ol is also being hovered but a li:hover selector will select only that li.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`li:hover` should not target your `ol`:

```css
li {
  border: 3px solid lightcoral;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: fit-content;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: fit-content;
}

li:hover {
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ol>
```

The problem probably lies elsewhere. Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).